# How to set up language in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, httprequest, puppeteer

I'm trying to load a webpage in a specific language using Puppeteer
I've tried many things such as put the language through both args and env, in the request header but it still somehow doesn't work.
Can someone help ?
I'm using puppeteer 5.5.0, node 16.2.0 & Windows 10.0.19042 
This is what I've tried so far :

```js
browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless, args: ['--lang=fr'], env: { LANGUAGE: "fr" }});
        
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
            'Accept-Language': 'fr'
});
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            Object.defineProperty(navigator, "language", {
                get: function() {
                    return "fr-FR";
                }
});
            Object.defineProperty(navigator, "languages", {
                get: function() {
                    return ["fr-FR", "fr"];
                }
            });
});
```

Additionally, my computer is in France and is set in French and when I load the targeted page in any "human" browser, it loads the page in French... I searched for similar issues on StackOverflow but I didn't manage to find a working solution.

Comment: based on your previous tries I suppose you want to open the page in French. normally your language settings are all correct, if you visit https://google.com you will see it is opened in French. maybe your webpage is using some extra GET parameters to set the language which they save into cookies and later if you open the page: it will remain on that language. but in general, it seems to be a site-specific issue.

Comment: Oh that's right, it actually opens google in French, I'll try to search for any "GET" parameter from the website and keep this post updated if I find anything, thanks for the help

Comment: Okay I finally found the problem, the language was set by a cookie and a get request, I managed to make puppeteer modify this cookie and the page was correctly loaded in french, thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: How do I close the question ? (sorry this is my first time publishing a question on stackoverflow)

Comment: glad you've solved it :) I suggest posting your solution as a standalone answer post (so: not in a comment) below. you can also accept it as the correct answer for yourself. it will be helpful for visitors of the future :)